# iOS Javascript replace \"

Tags: javascript, string

For some weird reason JSON.stringify on iOS escapes `"` with `\"` . It must be some bug somewhere in my code. However, in order to re-establish my working version, I must get rid of the `\"` and replace them with `"` . I tried 
`a.replace('\"','"')` but to no avail.

For instance, I get this where only the first \" expression is replaced.

```
> '\"\"'.replace('\"','@')
< "@\""
```

Please keep in mind that I am debugging on an iOS device through Safari

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Also, `'\"'` doesn't produce the string you think it does. *"However, in order to re-establish my working version, I must get rid of the `\"` and replace them with `"` "* Most likely not. Please provide an example of the data you are working with and what you are doing with it.

Comment: You'll need to post more code. `JSON.stringify()` is not broken. Your  `.replace()` example is behaving exactly as it should: you're replacing the first `"` character with `@`. In a string quoted with single-quote characters, `\"` is exactly the same as `"` by itself.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify would escape double quotes as JSON uses double quotes to encapsulate each name and value.

What are you stringify'ing? `JSON.parseJSON($json)` would undo stringify, and therefore the escaping (turns back into JavaScript object).